# FirebaseError: Expected type 'Ta', but it was: a custom oh object

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

Im retrieving a data from firebase collection named matches,im querying data based on user.uid .but im getting a error  FirebaseError: Expected type 'Ta', but it was: a custom oh object

```
import { View, Text } from "react-native";
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import useAuth from "../hooks/useAuth";
import { onSnapshot, query, where } from "firebase/firestore";
import { db } from "../firebase";

const Chatlist = () => {
  const [matches, setMatches] = useState([]);
  const { user } = useAuth();
  useEffect(
    () =>
      onSnapshot(
        query(db, "matches"),
        where("userMatched", "array-contains", user.uid)
      ),
    (snapshot) =>
    
      setMatches(
        snapshot.docs.map((doc) => ({
          id: doc.id,
          ...doc.data(),
        }))
        
      ),
    [user]
    
  );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The query constraints should be passed in `query()` function itself. Also `onSnapshot` 2nd parameter is the callback function. Try refactoring the code as shown below:

```
useEffect(() => {
  if (user) {
    const q = query(collection(db, "matches"), where("userMatched", "array-contains", user.uid))

    return onSnapshot(q, (snapshot) => {
      setMatches(
        snapshot.docs.map((doc) => ({
          id: doc.id,
          ...doc.data(),
        }))
      )
    })
  } else {
    console.log("No user logged in")
  }
}, [user])
```